# Capture the hash of each file - add to metadata of the file - uploading to aws s3

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload files to aws s3 - below script iterates through folder and uploads the file (directory and subdirectory). So far it works, but am not being able to capture the hash of the file and add it to metadata of each file.

## FUNCTION – Iterate through subfolders and upload files to S3

```
function RecurseFolders([string]$path) {
$fc = New-Object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject
$folder = $fc.GetFolder($path)
foreach ($i in $folder.SubFolders) {
 $thisFolder = $i.Path
```

# Transform the local directory path to notation compatible with S3 Buckets and Folders

```
 $s3Path = $thisFolder.ToString()
$s3Path = $s3Path.SubString(2)
```

# Escape the back-slash special character with a back-slash so that it reads it literally, like so: "\"

```
   $s3Path = $s3Path -replace "\\", "/"
$s3Path = "/" + $s3Folder + $s3Path
```

# Upload directory to S3

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $s3Bucket -Folder $thisFolder -KeyPrefix $s3Path
```

}

# If subfolders exist in the current folder, then iterate through them too

```
foreach ($i in $folder.subfolders) {
RecurseFolders($i.path)
```

}
}

## Upload root directory files to S3

```
$s3Path = "/" + $s3Folder + "/" + $sourceFolder
```

Write-S3Object -BucketName $s3Bucket -Folder $sourcePath -KeyPrefix $s3Path

## Upload subdirectories to S3

```
RecurseFolders($sourcePath)
```

Comment: To get file hash, there's a Powershell cmdlet called : `Get-FileHash` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: I am not being able to successfully implement it in the code (add it to metadata for each file before uploading to aws s3), thank you for your reply!